# AngularJS header returns 500 Internal Server Error from Webapi

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass a custom header to the webapi post method from my angularjs app. But it seems that webapi is not capturing the header information returning null to the request.

I have

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "xasdfYer3444";
```

in the app.js run method.

The request is as follows

```
   getAuthInfo: function (username, password,demographics) { 
   var dataObj= {username:username,password:password};  
   var getservice = $resource(baselocation + "api/account", null);
   return  getservice.save(dataObj);
```

In the web api I have

```
public IHttpActionResult index(HttpRequestMessage req,AccountParams acct)
{

     _accountinfo.request = req;
     return Ok(_accountinfo);

}
```

It returns 500 Internal server error. Can anybody figure out what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: 500 internal server error mean there is something wrong on api side you have to debug your api code.try your api using postman

Comment: check in developer console that in request headers , Authorization header is being sent.

Comment: Using postman I get the header back, but not with angular js code.